# C# monitor microphone usage

Tags: c#, winapi, audio

I'm looking for an ability in managed code to monitor which processes are accessing microphone devices on my computer.

I was able to find [C++ examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952704/grab-audio-sessions-as-they-appear-in-the-windows-audio-mixer-c-or-c) of viewing audio output (AudioSessionManager), but is there an API for input devices also?

Extended: How can one protect himself against microphone spying on Windows oeprating system?

Comment: The Windows operating system is above your program, hierarchy-wise. If it wants to use your microphone without anyone else noticing, it will. To the question: You can write a wrapper for that unmanaged code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controling-volume-mixer (the `IAudioSessionManager2` interace).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is for audio output. I'm looking for monitor usage of audio input. I understand that OS is above application, but I'm not protecting myself from "bad Microsoft OS" - I'm looking for protection against other "evil apps".

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I just need to know if the microphone is being used or not